# They say actions are louder than words

Tags: pattern

They say actions are louder than words

> 11 23 31 12 33 52 64 72 84 76 88

Who am I?

Comment: You're Going hamateur, I feel like we've been over this before

Comment: Woops quite forgetful of me I suppose...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you a

> white knight (chess piece)?

11 23 31 12 33 52 64 72 84 76 88

> The sequence represents positions on a chessboard. This is a tour that a knight chess piece could take from the lower left corner of the board to the top right corner.